# Timestamp in Firebase Simulator not allowed (.) dot

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

there's a JSON field called createdTime, its value is the Server's current timestamp (look like this {".sv":"timestamp"}), but the simulator doesn't allow having "." (dot) in field names. What should I do to simulate that?

[image: Here is the Image]

Comment: you can check server time stamp only in firebase database

Comment: We have a fix coming that will allow `.sv` keys in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's working now! :)

Comment: hi @avinadoid, is it still working for you ? we have a rule `validate: "newData.val() === now"` but there is no way to test writing that `now`... Internal error ....

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by `tstirrat` says,

> We have a fix coming that will allow `.sv` keys in the simulator.

it appears that this has been fixed as of today.

I made this answer so that this question is considered answered.